# Adjust the vertical spaces between two sections in Nomenclature, LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, nomenclature

I am using LyX to write my thesis, and I sort my notation into two sections ('Abbreviation' and 'Formula symbols and units') with `nomencl`.

I would like to insert some vertical space above the section 'Formula symbols and units'
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

The package `nomencl` uses the environment `\thenomenclature` to open the needed environment. If your documentclass uses `chapter` the environment will use the definition:

```
\chapter*{\nomname}
```

Otherwise the the header will be created by

```
\section*{\nomname}
```

In both cases the skip above is always the same as for normal `chapters` or `section`.